# Why one ng-app is working at a time?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 `div` each applied with a `ng-app`. But it is strange, that only one `ng-app` is working at a time. When I run the following :

```
<html>
<body>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.29/angular.min.js'></script>
    <div ng-app='myApp'>
        <span ng-controller="textController">{{greetMessage.ny}}</span>
    </div>  

    <div ng-app='transactionStatus'>
        <p ng-controller="transactionStatusController">
            <em>Hello&nbsp;{{transactionDetails.completeName}}</em> <br />
            Your current status: {{transactionDetails.statusText}}
        </p>
    </div>  

    <script>
        var myappModule = angular.module('myApp',[]);

        myappModule.controller('textController',function($scope) {
            var greetMessage = {};
            greetMessage.ny = 'Hey! Happy new year.';
            $scope.greetMessage = greetMessage;
        });

        var transactionStatusModule = angular.module('transactionStatus',[]);
        transactionStatusModule.controller('transactionStatusController',function($scope){
            var transactionDetails = {};
            transactionDetails.completeName = 'Brian Silas';
            transactionDetails.statusText = 'Confirmed';
            $scope.transactionDetails = transactionDetails;
        });
    </script>

</body>
```

the output is:

```
Hey! Happy new year.
Hello {{transactionDetails.completeName}} 
Your current status: {{transactionDetails.statusText}}
```

But if I remove the the div with `ng-app`, it works as expected and the output is :

```
Hello Brian Silas 
Your current status: Confirmed
```

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Angular keeps global state - it is impossible to have two angular applications at once on hte same DOM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular bootstraps only the first found application. More details [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap).

To have more than one application you need to manually bootstrap the second one:

```
angular.element(<your element>).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(<your element>, ['transactionStatus']);
});
```